# error while building ios app on VS15 using xamarin

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

I am very new to xamarin(visual studio) mobile platform and going good with 
android .
but when am building iOS app ,its throwing 2 errors

1. Could not find a usable Xcode app bundle in
2. The Apple iOS SDK is not installed.

I have already installed xamarin studio (COMMUNITY) on my MAC and all its component and already connected to Xamarin MAC agent.

I haven't installed XCODE on MAC , is it necessary ??

Please assist me how can I solve this build error

Comment: Yes. You need to install Xcode on your Mac build host. On the Mac, open the App Store, search "Xcode", install Xcode.

Comment: Dylan s, These errors are because of Xcode not installed on MAC??

Comment: Definitely you need Xcode. The agent syncs bits between PC and Mac to make sure your app can be compiled properly. It has been clearly documented by Xamarin, https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make things a little bit more clear in order to prevent confusion. You can have the following setups:

1. MacOS, with [Xamarin Studio](https://www.xamarin.com/studio) .
2. A Windows computer, with [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/) connected to a Mac over the network with the [Xamarin Mac Agent](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/) .

Both setups will need [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) installed on the Mac, which is needed because some of the internal tools that are installed with Xcode are used (like signing the `IPA` with a certificate and the Apple iOS SDK itself).

Choosing one of the setups is a matter of preference. A lot of people like Visual Studio because they're used to it and it has nice [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/) integration and works for Android/UWP and iOS. Others like Xamarin Studio (Android and iOS only) because of simplicity.

I hope this makes sense, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You do require XCode for iOS development. It is required for debugging and also for emulation of the iOS apps onto a iOS Simulator.

Even development on a MAC will require that it is installed with XCode.

[Click Here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/) to see a guide to connecting to a MAC. More on that, that guide does say that your connected MAC must have XCode installed.

[Click here](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) for a link to XCode.